# Datetime field overflow error while inserting

Tags: sql, mysql, date, sql-insert

I have a table `test_a`

```
CREATE TABLE `test_a` (
  `CUSTOMER_RK`         int         DEFAULT NULL,
  `CUSTOMER_STATUS`     varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EFFECTIVE_FROM_DTTM` date        DEFAULT NULL,
  `EFFECTIVE_TO_DTTM`   date        DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Filled Like so:

| CUSTOMER_RK | CUSTOMER_STATUS | EFFECTIVE_FROM_DTTM | EFFECTIVE_TO_DTTM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2004-01-20 | 2015-02-23 |
| 1 | B | 2016-02-24 | 2016-05-17 |
| 1 | A | 2017-05-18 | 9999-12-31 |
| 2 | B | 1998-09-01 | 2018-09-04 |
| 2 | A | 2018-09-05 | 2018-09-06 |
| 2 | B | 2019-09-07 | 2019-09-07 |
| 2 | A | 2019-09-08 | 9999-12-31 |

Tried to insert result of this select query in my table with this code:

```
INSERT INTO test_a (
    CUSTOMER_RK, CUSTOMER_STATUS, EFFECTIVE_FROM_DTTM, EFFECTIVE_TO_DTTM
)
SELECT
    CUSTOMER_RK,
    CUSTOMER_STATUS,
    EFFECTIVE_FROM_DTTM,
    EFFECTIVE_TO_DTTM
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            CUSTOMER_RK,
            CUSTOMER_STATUS,
            DATE_ADD( EFFECTIVE_TO_DTTM, INTERVAL 1 DAY ) AS EFFECTIVE_FROM_DTTM,
            DATE_SUB( LEAD( EFFECTIVE_FROM_DTTM, 1, '9999-12-31' ) OVER ( ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_FROM_DTTM ), INTERVAL 1 DAY ) AS EFFECTIVE_TO_DTTM

        FROM
            test_a AS a1
        WHERE
            CUSTOMER_RK = 1
    ) AS a2
WHERE
    EFFECTIVE_FROM_DTTM < EFFECTIVE_TO_DTTM;
```

But got this error:

```
18:53:59    INSERT INTO test_a (CUSTOMER_RK, CUSTOMER_STATUS, EFFECTIVE_FROM_DTTM, EFFECTIVE_TO_DTTM) SELECT CUSTOMER_RK, CUSTOMER_STATUS, EFFECTIVE_FROM_DTTM, EFFECTIVE_TO_DTTM FROM ( SELECT CUSTOMER_RK, CUSTOMER_STATUS, DATE_ADD(EFFECTIVE_TO_DTTM, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS EFFECTIVE_FROM_DTTM,  DATE_SUB(LEAD(EFFECTIVE_FROM_DTTM, 1, '9999-12-31') OVER (ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_FROM_DTTM), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS EFFECTIVE_TO_DTTM FROM test_a AS a1 WHERE CUSTOMER_RK = 1 ) AS a2 WHERE EFFECTIVE_FROM_DTTM < EFFECTIVE_TO_DTTM

Error Code: 1441. Datetime function: datetime field overflow    0.000 sec
```

Why am I getting this error?

**Upd.:**

MySQL version: `8.0.34`

sql_mode: `'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'`

Result of `SELECT '9999-12-31' + INTERVAL 1 DAY;` was `NULL`

Comment: `DATE_ADD( EFFECTIVE_TO_DTTM, INTERVAL 1 DAY )` will add 1 day to `9999-12-31` which will overflow. You probably should use `NULL` as the `default` in `LEAD()`.

Comment: The first victim of the Y10k bug

Comment: Tryed `LEAD(EFFECTIVE_FROM_DTTM, 1, NULL)` but got same error

Comment: @OleksandrZakharchenko Please recreate the issue on https://dbfiddle.uk/ and post the link here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot figure out what MySQL version and sql_mode combination will lead to this. Please add the following to your question as I am intrigued to know:

1. MySQL version (`SELECT VERSION();`)
2. sql_mode (`SELECT @@sql_mode;`)
3. Result of `SELECT '9999-12-31' + INTERVAL 1 DAY;`

**UPDATE**: Thank you for adding the answers to the above to your question. I don't know what I was doing/thinking when I looked at this last night, but it was easy to reproduce.

You can avoid it by NULLing the problematic value.

Change

```sql
DATE_ADD( EFFECTIVE_TO_DTTM, INTERVAL 1 DAY ) AS EFFECTIVE_FROM_DTTM,
```

to

```sql
DATE_ADD( NULLIF(EFFECTIVE_TO_DTTM, '9999-12-31'), INTERVAL 1 DAY ) AS EFFECTIVE_FROM_DTTM,
```

IMHO, a better option is to store a more appropriate value when the `EFFECTIVE_TO_DTTM` is unknown, such as `NULL`.

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ramcZpZ3).

Comment: added what you asked to the question

Comment: Thank you. I have added a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ramcZpZ3).